# Android DialogFragment views don't get updated when I call show method with explicit setText calls

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to create a fragment that, when shown, changes it's content based on an extra item I pass on the `show()` method. The dialog fragment instance is kept for reusability, in other words, I just instantiate the fragment once and call `show()` with the new object it displays whenever I want it to be displayed. It works fine for the first time it is shown, but for subsequent calls to show, I just can't change the text of the edit texts. You'll see in my class below that I've actually explicitly made the text to be changed to "I was changed" after the `show()` code block, but this never reflects in the ui.

```
public class RegisterFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener
    {
    private static final String KEY_SOURCE = "source";
    private static String source;
    private static JSONObject listEntry;
    private RegisterItem item;

    private boolean spinnerMode;
    private boolean viewsCreated;

    private TextView label1, label2;
    private EditText field1 = null, field2 = null;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private Button send, cancel;

    private OnClickSendCancelButtonListener sendListener;

    public static RegisterFragment newInstance(String source)
        {
        RegisterFragment fragment = new RegisterFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(KEY_SOURCE, source);
        fragment.setArguments(b);
        return fragment;
        }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle b = this.getArguments();
        if (b != null)
            {
            source = b.getString(KEY_SOURCE);
            load(source);
            }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        viewsCreated = false;
        }


    public RegisterItem getRegisterItem()
        {
        return this.item;   
        }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
        {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try
            {
            this.sendListener = (OnClickSendCancelButtonListener) activity;
            }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
            {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement RegisterFragment#OnClickSendCancelButtonListener");
            }
        }

    private void load(String source)
        {
        if (item == null)
            item = new RegisterItem();
        item.loadData(source);
        spinnerMode = item.hasChoices();

        if (!viewsCreated)
            return;

        label1.setText(item.field1Label);
        label2.setText(item.field2Label);

        send.setText(item.sendButtonText);
        cancel.setText(item.cancelButtonText);

        Log.v("RegisterFragment", "FIELD1: " + item.defaultField1);
        Log.v("RegisterFragment", "FIELD2: " + item.defaultField2);

        if (spinnerMode)
            {
            field1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            adapter.clear();
            for(String choice: item.choices)
                adapter.add(choice);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        else
            {
            field1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        if (item.hasDefaults())
            {
            Log.v("RegisterFragment", "Setting text for field 2");
            field2.setText(item.defaultField2);
            Log.v("RegisterFragment", "FIELD2 TEXT: " + field2.getText().toString());
            if (spinnerMode)
                spinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(item.defaultField2));
            else
                field1.setText(item.defaultField1);
            }
        }

    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag, String source, String listEntry)
        {
        Log.v("Register Fragment", "Showing fragment\nSOURCE STRING: " + source);
        load(source);
        RegisterFragment.source = source;
        try {
            RegisterFragment.listEntry = new JSONObject(listEntry);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.show(manager, tag);
        if (field2 != null)
            field2.setText("I Have Been Changed");
        }


    @Override
    public void dismiss()
        {
        if (field1 != null)
            field1.setText("");
        if (field2 != null)
            field2.setText("");
        super.dismiss();
        }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_screen, null);

        spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.register_spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        label1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.register_label1);
        label2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.register_label2);

        field1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.register_field1);
        field2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.register_field2);

        send = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.register_send);
        cancel = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.register_cancel);

        send.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        viewsCreated = true;
        load(source);

        return v;
        }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        viewsCreated = false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should have worked . But do try this.

```
EditText text = (EditText)getDialog().findViewById(R.id.register_field2);
text.setText("I have been changed");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, this throws a null pointer exception because the result of getDialog().findViewById() is null.